# If I complexify the action of a compact Lie group on a f.d. real vector space, are the orbits closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and let $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space with a faithful action of $G$ given by a Lie group embedding $G\hookrightarrow GL_\mathbb{R}(V)$. Then the orbits of $G$ in $V$ are closed, because they are compact, because they are the images of the compact space $G$ under the continuous map $g\mapsto gv$ ($v\in V$ fixed).

Meanwhile, $G$ can be viewed as an algebraic group defined over $\mathbb{R}$ (in fact, a Zariski-closed subset of $GL_\mathbb{R}(V)$). (I learned this from Onischchik and Vinberg's book *Lie Groups and Algebraic Groups*, Ch. 3, Sec. 4, Thm. 5.) Then the action map $G\times V\rightarrow V$ is a polynomial map defined over $\mathbb{R}$ because multiplication of a matrix by a vector is polynomial in the coordinates.

The complexification $G_\mathbb{C}$ of $G$ is reductive, and every reductive algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$ arises this way. (Again, Onishchik and Vinberg, this time Ch. 5, Sec. 5, Thm. 12.)

In general, $G_\mathbb{C}$ need not act on a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space with closed orbits. For example if $G=S^1$, the circle group, then $G_\mathbb{C}$ is $GL_1(\mathbb{C})$, whose action by scaling on $\mathbb{C}^n$ famously has the origin contained in the closure of every orbit.

However, what specifically about the action of $G_\mathbb{C}$ on $V_\mathbb{C}:=\mathbb{C}\otimes_\mathbb{R} V$, defined just by base-changing the original action map $G\times V\rightarrow V$ to $\mathbb{C}$?

> **Are the orbits of $G_\mathbb{C}$ on $V_\mathbb{C}$ closed?**

In summary, if the action of a reductive algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$ on a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space arises by complexifying the action of its compact real form on a real vector space, does it have closed orbits?

(I think the answer should be yes, based on working out the case of $S^1\cong SO(2)$'s canonical action on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by hand, and some hand-wavy logic involving the fact that the action map is defined over $\mathbb{R}$, but it's very far from a real argument. Thank you in advance for your help.)

**Addendum:** As Moishe Kohan notes in comments, my conclusion for $SO(2)$ was actually wrong. Even for this action, the orbits are not all closed.  (I've written this up as an answer in order to have something to accept.) This is probably not of interest except to me, but, here I will record how I came to this false conclusion:

- I viewed $G$'s variety structure as coming from the ring $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$.
- Then $G_\mathbb{C}$'s variety structure comes from this ring tensored up to $\mathbb{C}$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]$ via $t=x+iy$.
- Then, I parametrized the orbits of the action in terms of $t$. They had coordinates with shapes like $(t+t^{-1})u+i(t-t^{-1})v$.
- I reasoned that as $t\to 0,\infty$, one of $t$ or $t^{-1}$ will always blow up, so these coordinates will always blow up, except if $u=v=0$. (False! See next bullet.) Thus the nonzero orbits all go off to infinity as $t\to 0,\infty$, so how will we get any limit points from $t\to 0,\infty$? So the orbits are closed. (Again, false, see below.)
- While this works for most orbits, I didn't consider that $u$ and $v$ can be chosen to make either the $t$'s or the $t^{-1}$'s cancel out. So special choices of $u$ and $v$ will have coordinates with shapes like $t$ or $t^{-1}$, where you do get 0 as a limit point (as $t\to 0,\infty$ respectively). [In fact, the special choices of $u$ and $v$ are the eigenvectors for the action.]

Comment: I don't have time to think about this very much right now, but I'd be surprised if this were true. It would somehow have to do with the algebraic structure of $V$ being simple. For example, you could ask whether or not your question holds more generally: if $G$ is anisotropic gorup over $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. one whose $\mathbb{R}$-points are compact) acting on a variety $X$, is it true that the orbits of $G_\mathbb{C}$ acting on $X_\mathbb{C}$ are closed. The answer is then no as one can see by taking $G$ acting on itself by conjugation. Somehow I think the $SO(2)$ case could be misleading

Comment: since closedness of orbits has to do with a generaliaztion of notions of semisimplicity, and $SO(2)$ is a torus. For example, if you have a torus acting linearly then the orbits will just be linear subspaces of $V_\mathbb{C}$, no? Have you tried thinking about higher rank unitary groups? I might just be being silly though. I'll think more later.

Comment: Thanks @AlexYoucis - working out, e.g., $SU(2)$ by hand sounds like a lot of work, but maybe worth it. Not sure what you're saying about a torus acting linearly having linear subspaces as orbits? E.g. for the canonical action of the diagonal group on $\mathbb{C}^n$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$, the orbits other than the origin are not closed in either case. (There's a big orbit consisting of the complement of the coordinate hyperplanes, whose closure is everything; and then that picture is repeated in lower dimensions inside the coordinate hyperplanes.)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question, but the standard action of ${\mathbb C}^\times$ on ${\mathbb C}^2$ is exactly the complexification of the standard action of $S^1$ on ${\mathbb R}^2$, so you know that $G_{\mathbb C}$-orbits are not closed in this case. As for actions of  semisimple groups, the situation is more complicated but the answer is the same. In fact, Mumford's GIT is built around exactly this issue: Stable orbits are closed, unstable orbits are not. Life is more interesting in the semistable case, and "closed orbits" turns out to be the wrong question (Mumford vs. Kostant).

Comment: Ah, @MoisheKohan, ok so by "standard action of $\mathbb{C}^\times$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ you must mean $\alpha\mapsto diag(\alpha,\alpha^{-1})$. I see the flaw in my argument that the orbits are closed. (I parametrized the orbits and it seemed to me they couldn't have any finite limit points they didn't already contain, but with more care, two special ones do.) So, yeah, this answers the question.

Comment: @MoisheKohan - In view of this exchange, I would like to thank you in an acknowledgement in a written work. Is "Moishe Kohan" how you are known professionally?

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith: No, this is not my real/professional  name (my MSE user name is obtained by combining names of my grandfathers) and I prefer to remain anonymous. As for how to cite in this situation, take a look for instance here: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4351/how-to-cite-comment-by-unknown-user-disproving-erd%c5%91s-conjecture?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @MoisheKohan, thank you, ok I will proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moishe Kohan notes in comments that the answer is no, even on the basis of the example mentioned in the OP.

The complexification of the canonical action of $S^1$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is isomorphic to the action of $\mathbb{C}^\times$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ via the diagonal matrices

$$\begin{pmatrix}\alpha & \\ &\alpha^{-1}\end{pmatrix}, \;\alpha\in\mathbb{C}^\times.$$

The rotation matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$, with eigenvectors $(1,i)$ and $(1,-i)$. The rotation through $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$ has eigenvalues $e^{i\theta}$ and $e^{-i\theta}$ respectively. So letting $\alpha = e^{i\theta}$, we get the action just described. I am omitting details.

This action does not have closed orbits. Most of the orbits are closed, but two of the orbits are the two one-dimensional linear spaces spanned by the eigenvectors of the action, minus the origin. So even in this instance, the action of $G_\mathbb{C}$ does not have closed orbits.